# Angularjs ng-grid Highlight row dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have following ng-grid.

```
  $scope.IssueGrid = {
            data: 'IssueGridList',
            multiSelect: false,
            selectedItems: $scope.selectedRow,
            enableColumnResize: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            headerRowHeight: 65,
            columnDefs: [

                { field: 'Item', width: '25%', displayName: 'Item Name' },
                { field: 'RequiredQuantity', displayName: 'Requested Qty', cellTemplate: '<div style="text-align:right;"  class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' },
                { field: '', width: '7%', displayName: 'To be Issued', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText {{row.entity.cellClass}}"> <input type="text" id="issQty" style="text-align:right;" data-ng-change="editIssueQty(row)" data-ng-model="row.entity.IssueQty" number-only-input input-value = "row.entity.IssueQty" class="form-control" data-ng-disabled="issueQtyDisabled(row.entity)" value = {{row.getProperty(col.IssueQty)}} /></div>' },
                ],
            showFooter: true
        };
```

This grid has text box to enter "IssueQty". But when ever value is entered to
Issued quantity, if it is greater than "RequiredQuantity" entire row should be Highlighted.

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this..

Thanks and regards.

Comment: you can have a watch function for "IssueQty" variable and then if the value is changed apply CSS class using ng-class.

Comment: @NehaSaggam.. Can't put watch statement because "IssueQty" is within cell template. any other suggestions.. thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `rowTemplate` (see [Row Templates](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/)) that uses `ng-class` and `row.getProperty` to set a 'highlight' class for the entire row.

```
rowTemplate:'<div ng-style="rowStyle(row)" ng-class="{highlighted: row.getProperty(\'IssueQty\') > row.getProperty(\'RequiredQuantity\') }"><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
                       '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div>' +
                       '<div ng-cell></div>' +
                 '</div></div>'
```

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("myApp", ['ngGrid'])
    .controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.IssueGridList = [
      {Item:'test1', RequiredQuantity:1, IssueQty:0},
      {Item:'test2', RequiredQuantity:2, IssueQty:0}
    ];

    $scope.IssueGrid = {
      data: 'IssueGridList',
      multiSelect: false,
      //selectedItems: $scope.selectedRow,
      enableColumnResize: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      showFooter: true,
      columnDefs: [

                { field: 'Item', width: '25%', displayName: 'Item Name' },
                { field: 'RequiredQuantity', width:'25%', displayName: 'Requested Qty', cellTemplate: '<div style="text-align:right;"  class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' },
                { field: '', width: '50%', displayName: 'To be Issued', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText {{row.entity.cellClass}}"> <input type="text" id="issQty" style="text-align:right;" data-ng-change="editIssueQty(row)" data-ng-model="row.entity.IssueQty" number-only-input input-value = "row.entity.IssueQty" class="form-control" data-ng-disabled="issueQtyDisabled(row.entity)" value = {{row.getProperty(col.IssueQty)}} /></div>' },
                ],
        
        rowTemplate:'<div ng-style="rowStyle(row)" ng-class="{highlighted: row.getProperty(\'IssueQty\') > row.getProperty(\'RequiredQuantity\') }"><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
                           '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div>' +
                           '<div ng-cell></div>' +
                     '</div></div>'
    };
  }

})();
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px;
}
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="IssueGrid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in your code -

```
        <input type="text" ng-style="{'background-color':'{{change}}'}" ng-change="anyFunction()">
```

and in the controller you can write a function to change the css of that particular textbox.Like -

```
          .controller('myApp',['$scope',function($scope){
           $scope.change = /*any default value of color here*/
           $scope.anyFunction = function{
             /*if(required value greater than the demo quantity)
                  then change = /*your desired color*/;
             */
           }

             ])
```